# Why does my zsh prompt wander upwards when window is too narrow?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zsh, xterm

I have a weird behaviour that seems to be a combination of zsh and maybe urxvt (?)
My setup is this: I start `urxvt -e 'tmux'` to get myself a terminal which launches `zsh` as the default shell.

I then started customizing my `$PROMPT` and it currently looks like this:

```
 zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git svn hg bzr
 zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats $' \e[0;33m(%s:%b)\e[0m'
 precmd () { vcs_info }
 PROMPT+=$'\e[0;31m%n\e[0m'
 PROMPT+="@"
 PROMPT+=$'\e[0;34m%m\e[0m'
 PROMPT+=":"
 PROMPT+=$'\e[0;36m%3c\e[0m'
 PROMPT+=$'\e[0;33m%c\e[0m'
 PROMPT+='${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
 export PROMPT
```

You might notice the second `%c` line, that is, of course, for testing.

The normal behaviour of a prompt is to create a new line after pressing enter, optionally executing the command that may be present. The a new line is printed. However, I notice a different behaviour under certain circumstances: When I press enter, the command is executed and the output is displayed. **However**, when the previous prompt was not at the top of the terminal, the last line of previous output is overwritten because the whole new output is moved one line upwards.

Maybe an example is in order. Start with an empty terminal and a new prompt:

```
user@hostname:very long directory name/with multiple components/foo~very long directory name/with multiple components/foo (git:master)
```

Now we enter `ls -la` in this  directory (sample output):

```
user@hostname:very long directory name/with multiple components/foo~very long directory name/with multiple components/foo (git:master)ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 ..
user@hostname:very long directory name/with multiple components/foo~very long directory name/with multiple components/foo (git:master)
```

Notice how there is something missing, as in reality, there is a `.git` directory in here:

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 .git
```

What happened here is easily described: The command output is generated correctly but then the prompt line is moved up by one line and overwrites the last line of output. So if I do the same again, my output looks like this:

```
user@hostname:very long directory name/with multiple components/foo~very long directory name/with multiple components/foo (git:master)ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 .
user@hostname:very long directory name/with multiple components/foo~very long directory name/with multiple components/foo (git:master)ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 user user 4096 25. Jan 16:17 ..
user@hostname:very long directory name/with multiple components/foo~very long directory name/with multiple components/foo (git:master)
```

As you can see, everything was moved up once again, this time replacing the `..` from the last output and the `.git` from this output.

But this does not happen on all setups. It only happens, when the window is too narrow. I additionally, tested this by resizing the open urxvt window with zsh inside. When I make it too narrow. From what I see it starts once the prompt takes up about two thirds of the windows width. However, I don't know **why** this happens on this occassion.

Some notes:
- It does not happen with bash (even when the prompt itself is multiline)
- `RPROMPT` and `RPROMPT2` are empty
- It does not seem to depend on the type of information displayed (i.e. disabling `vcs_info` only helps if the prompt gets short enough again)
- It does not happen when the prompt is multiline (and the second line does not reach the two-thirds mark)
- It does not happen in a console (tty), but it does happen with xterm *and* urxvt.

**Summary**: My zsh prompt moves when line upwards if the prompt line is about two thirds of the window long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have fixed it by using `%{fg[color]%}` instead of the bash color codes (of course for that I need to load the color module).